# How to add clickable link/dialog box to Backbone.js JST EJS file

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I need to create a modal dialog (just click OK) in a Backbone.js template file. It is in a loop like this, in show_template.jst.ejs:

```
<% for(var i = 0... all words %>
<% var word = get the ith word %>
<td><span class="synonyms"><%= I18n.t("Synonyms") %></span></td>
```

I want the user to be able to click on "Synonyms" (in her chosen language) and have a modal dialog box pop up, and show the synonyms from the database, in her language.
To sum up, I want Synonyms to be clickable.

Could someone point me in the right direction? (I am a Javascript/Backbone.js noob)

Comment: Assuming that you have a view that's attached to the parent element of where ever this template gets rendered you will want to [bind](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-delegateEvents) to the click event for the *synonyms* class. Its a little bit hard to be more specific without more information, what does your view/model look like?

Comment: @Jack, thanks very much for answering. Let me be explicitly clear- I have not yet written a View/Model for Synonyms. Synonym will be created in ActiveRecord (Rails front-end), and it will be a very simple class, which will receive a word, and return zero or more synonyms which match the word. So I think I am understanding from you- I need to create a View/Model for Synonym, and inside that definition, there will be a click event. Is that right?

Comment: You don't need to necessarily do it that way, but you need to bind a click event handler somewhere, it could be in a view, or it can just be elsewhere. It really depends on how your code/page is being structured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I see two options for making Synonyms clickable and knowing which one was clicked

**One View option** - put your data on the dom and read it upon a click action: (**notice the data-kind attribute**)

```
<% for(var i = 0... all words %>
<% var word = get the ith word %>
<td>
    <span class="synonyms" data-kind='<%= I18n.t("Synonyms") %>' >
        <%= I18n.t("Synonyms") %>
    </span>
</td>
```

And the event part of the view will look like this

```
events: {
   "click .synonums" : "synonyms_event"
},

synonyms_event: function(e) {
    var kind =  $(e.target).data("kind");
    alert(kind + " was pressed");
}
```

The other option is to **create views for each word** and let it take care of the click event